# Oracle SQL to Check a value against a specific list of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I got the SQLfiddle link copied below for my required.

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1
(COL1 NUMBER,
 COL2 NUMBER,
 COL3 NUMBER,
 COL4 NUMBER);

 INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES(1,2,3,2);
 INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES(1,2,1,2);
 INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES(1,2,2,2);
 INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES(1,2,2,2);
```

I want to check if columns col2, col3,col4 has the value 2. I have the below sql to achieve my requirement. But the problem is I have to check the same for 300 columns. Table is already designed like this by the developer as per incoming data file and I can't change anything now. Is there a better way of doing this other than using the below SQL with 300 column names in ALL(col1..col300)?

```
SELECT *
  FROM TAB1
 WHERE 2 = ALL (COL2,COL3,COL4);
```

SQLfiddle link is below with expected output

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbc00/3/0

Appreciate the responses. Thank you

Comment: That's a really bad design. I doubt you can do it without naming all 300 columns one by one. The only alternate solution would be to get the metadata of the table and assemble dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: @TheImpaler, Thanks for the response. Data file comes just like that with 300 columns infact more columns included, What do you think a better design for this table. I could propose this atleast to my client and give it a try. And there is more to add on this and I am going with dynamic SQL for that additional functionality which I am good with.

Comment: The whole idea of columns is that each one represents a distinct attribute of the entity. Your query is like `where 'x' = all (first_name, middle_name, last_name)`. To normalise that, you would store all names in one column of a `names` table and look for cases where the number of `x`s matched the number of rows, or perhaps where there was no row that was not `x`.

Answer (score 1):

As The Impaler said, dynamic SQL could help. If you can't fix that design, see if something like this helps: function accepts *search value* as a parameter, uses query you already wrote and returns refcursor.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_ok (par_search_value in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str  varchar2(32000) := 'select * From tab1 where ' || par_search_value ||' = all(';
  5    l_rc   sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select column_name
  8                  from user_tab_columns
  9                  where table_name = 'TAB1'
 10                    and column_id > 1
 11                  order by column_id
 12                 )
 13    loop
 14      l_str := l_str || cur_r.column_name || ', ';
 15    end loop;
 16    l_str := rtrim(l_str, ', ') || ')';
 17    open l_rc for l_str;
 18    return l_rc;
 19  end;
 20  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from tab1;

      COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3          2
         1          2          1          2
         1          2          2          2
         1          2          2          2

SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec :rc := f_ok(2);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

      COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          2          2
         1          2          2          2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, unfortunately wanted to do it single query and now the requirement also changed. So redesigning the procedure that uses this query. Thanks all for trying to help.